# Implementar edição de contatos depois de gravados no banco de dados

Tags: java, android

Olá!

Estou adaptando um `aplicativo` que gerencia contatos com interação do `banco de dados`.

No `aplicativo`, estou inserindo e deletando contatos porém estou com dificuldades para implementar o `método` de editar os contatos e gravar o contato editado no `banco de dados`.

O `método` `onContextItemSelected` está implementado e falta somente essa parte.

**onContextItemSelected method na MainActivity**

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case EDIT:
            // TODO: Implement editing a contact
            break;
        case DELETE:
            dbHandler.deleteContact(Contacts.get(longClickedItemIndex));
            Contacts.remove(longClickedItemIndex);
            contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**Classe DatabaseHandler com o método updateContact**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "controleAgenda",
        TABLE_CONTACTS = "contatos",
        KEY_ID = "id",
        KEY_NAME = "nome",
        KEY_PHONE = "telefone",
        KEY_ADDRESS = "endereco",
        KEY_EMAIL = "email",
        KEY_IMAGEURI = "imageUri";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURI + " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void createContact(Contato contato) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, contato.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE, contato.getPhone());
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contato.getAddress());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contato.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contato.getImageURI().toString());

    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public Contato getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PHONE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_IMAGEURI }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contato contato = new Contato(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return contato;
}

public void deleteContact(Contato contato) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contato.getId()) });
    db.close();
}

public int getContactsCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return count;
}

public int updateContact(Contato contato) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, contato.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE, contato.getPhone());
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contato.getAddress());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contato.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contato.getImageURI().toString());

    int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contato.getId()) });
    db.close();

    return rowsAffected;
}

public List<Contato> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contato> contacts = new ArrayList<Contato>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contacts.add(new Contato(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5))));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return contacts;
}
}
```

Comment: Explique melhor a dificuldade que tem. Dá algum erro?

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo retorno @ramaral. Minha dificuldade na verdade é para implementar o método necessário para ediitar o contato, inclusive se minha questão não for pertinente a esse fórum, peço desculpas. Na classe que controla as ações e interações com o BD `(DatabaseHandler)`, já foi implementado o método `updateContact` Não estou conseguindo implementar essa edição da mesma forma que foi implementado para deleta-lo, no método `onContextItemSelected` presente na `MainActivity`.

Comment: Em realação ao banco deve chamar o método `dbHandler.updateContact(Contacts.get(longClickedItemIndex))`. No que diz respeito ao *adapter* não sei dizer porque não o conheço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando se quer editar um contato de alguma aplicação, o que geralmente é feito é o seguinte:

Ao clicar em um contato de uma lista de contatos, uma nova tela de edição ( activity ou fragment ) com as informações do contato clicado é aberta ( **Obs.:** as informações dos contatos podem ser passadas para a nova tela usando `Bundle`).

A tela de edição  possuirá `EditTexts` preenchidos com as informações do contato clicado, pois dessa maneira, caso você queira editar o nome do contato, basta editar o nome preenchido no `EditText`. Obviamente, essa tela também possui um botão de salvar alterações e um de cancelar alterações.

Assim, ao clicar no botão de salvar as alterações, você deve fazer o seguinte:

1. ( Ideal) Verificar se os dados são válidos
2. Criar um novo usuário utilizando os novos dados preenchidos no EditText ( apenas crie o novo contato usando o **new**, **Não adicione-o ao banco ainda!** );
3. ( Ideal, mas depende da lógica de negócio) Fazer uma consulta no banco com o novo usuário para verificar se os dados do novo usuário são conflitantes com de outro usuário já cadastrado.
4. Chamar a função de update do banco passando como parâmetro o novo
5. Notificar ao adapter que os dados do banco foram alterados.
6. Fechar a tela de edição e voltar para a tela anterior.

Esta é uma maneira "simples e geral" para se fazer alterações de cadastros. Caso você tenha alguma dúvida na implementação de um desses passos, ou consiga uma maneira mais simple de fazê-lo, sinta-se a vontade em compartilha-los.